# Grails fails to realize Domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 3.1.4, I've created some domain object and written unit test.
Tests are executed fine on my computer.

[Tests on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJBol.png)

But on the other developpers computers and on the continous integration platform, tests fail with exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [ ] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. If you are unit testing your entities using the mocking APIs
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.stateException(GormEnhancer.groovy:159)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findValidationApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:173)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidateable$Trait$Helper.currentGormValidationApi(GormValidateable.groovy:120)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidateable$Trait$Helper.validate(GormValidateable.groovy:87)
at com.cscinfo.platform.constraint.CascadeValidationConstraint.validateValue(CascadeValidationConstraint.groovy:43)
at com.cscinfo.platform.constraint.CascadeValidationConstraint.processValidateWithVetoing_closure1(CascadeValidationConstraint.groovy:29)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
at com.cscinfo.platform.constraint.CascadeValidationConstraint.processValidateWithVetoing(CascadeValidationConstraint.groovy:28)
at grails.validation.AbstractVetoingConstraint.validateWithVetoing(AbstractVetoingConstraint.java:33)
at grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.validate(ConstrainedProperty.java:967)
at org.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:211)
at org.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:81)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidationApi.doValidate(GormValidationApi.groovy:89)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidationApi.validate(GormValidationApi.groovy:161)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidateable$Trait$Helper.validate(GormValidateable.groovy:87)
at api.mails.MailSpec.Test la validation d'un mail incorrect 2(MailSpec.groovy:66)
```

It seems that GORM can't get my domain object.

I can't reproduce the bug on my computer.
Any help or documentation will be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: Are you using the same dataSources on dev and prod?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was some oject in my Unit test were not mocked.
I put an array of object in my @Mock annotation and now, it works on my continuous integration platform.

```
@TestFor(SMTPMailerService)
@Mock([Mail, DestinataireMail, PieceJointeMail])
class SMTPMailerServiceSpec extends Specification {
```

Hope it will help someone !

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  Spent the day tracking this down and your answer solved the problem!